# Do web crawlers read the HTTP headers?

Tags: http, https, web-crawler, bots

I own a url shortening service and I want to detect whether the request that I received was from a web crawler or not. In response to the request, I send a HTTP header 302 that redirects the requester to the original link. I was thinking that I could provide an invisible link with the response, so that a bot would send me a request for that page too but a normal user wont. This is based on the hypothesis that even if bots read the header and redirects, they still scans the page and send requests to the links found in it. Is the hypothesis correct? If it is not, I could also redirect them via Javascript but that would not be the standard way of redirecting(I suppose).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, crawlers definitely follow redirects. Their purpose is to find as many pages (or content) as possible. Following redirects is a basic requirement for that goal. However, I do not know if commercial crawlers read the body of a redirect response. I think they don't since information displayed on a redirect page is never shown to a user since they are always redirected away from that page.

There are other crawlers like [Crawljax](http://crawljax.com) that are build for testing web applications. They will read all the data but those crawlers aren't (or shouldn't be) used to crawl the public web.